# When did most East Prussians start speaking German?

Tags: history

According to [Gedanken und Fakten zur Bevölkerungsentwicklung in Ostpreußen](https://www.vffow.de/assets/downloads/dateien/gedanken-und-fakten-zur-bevoelkerungsentwicklu.pdf), even as late as 1708, only 25% of East Prussians were `deutsch` (Presumably, these were the people whose primary language was German)

When did *most* (>50%) East Prussians start speaking German? (More broadly, how did the fraction of German speakers in East Prussia change over time?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Prussia

In year 1824, shortly before its merger with West Prussia, the population of East Prussia was 1,080,000 people.[7] Of that number, according to Karl Andree, **Germans were slightly more than half**, while 280,000 (~26%) were ethnically Polish and 200,000 (~19%) were ethnically Lithuanian.[8]